# C Quest: disable input values

Tags: c

Hi devs: supposing you want to use a `scanf()` to acquire some integers in input, is there a way to disable the entry of any other characters other than 0-9? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Use some other function to read the whole line (like e.g. `fgets`), then use some other function to convert the string to an integer with validation (like `strtol`, or `sscanf` remembering to check what it returns).

Comment: Generally no.  Keep in mind that standard input does not always come from a user typing into a shell; it could also come from a file for example.

Comment: Disable in what way? Slap the user on the wrist if his finger touches a letter key?

Comment: If the question is, "Is there a way to limit user input to...?", the answer is always that while there may be a way to, it is either impossible using scanf, or three times harder than using some non-scanf alternative.

Comment: Depending on OS, you can use system APIs to override keyboard input, but it's not worth it to go down that road.

Comment: In a GUI, in a user-entry dialog box, you can do things like disable certain keys, or change the background color to red and disable the "OK" button whenever the user's input is malformed.  But in C's input model, the user is going to type what the user is going to type, and hit Return, and then your code has to figure out how to deal with it.  You can detect an error and print an error message and ask the user to try again, but you can't force him to not type what he's already typed.  And with `scanf` it's even worse, because  the unparseable input is still sitting there on the input stream.

Comment: (...And you can ask, "Okay, so after `scanf` has failed, how do I flush the unparseable input?", but that way lies madness.  Or rather, that way lies `fflush(stdin)`, which is about the same thing as madness.)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. There's a great scene for a Harry Potter movie there, with a little disembodied green hand magically popping up out of a wizard laptop's keyboard to do the slapping.

Comment: While you cannot stop users to type any key they want, or the input redirected to a file to contain any character, you can write some code to read one character at a time and do whatever you want if it is not a digit. This includes ignoring, printing a warning, or exiting the application. -- For example, the mentioned GUI entry field simply ignores.

Comment: You could try to use the `scanf` discarding feature.
`scanf("%*c");`

Comment: That little `*` reads and discards characters.